# Shell script cannot be executed from some directories even though its directory is added to the "PATH" variable

Tags: linux, shell

I wrote the following basic script and saved it as `my_script`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# My first script

echo "Hello World!"
```

I then ran the following command: `chmod 755 my_script` to give the shell permission to execute the script. I placed this script in my `bin` directory, which is a subdirectory of my user (macbook > bin). I added this directory to my path by executing `export PATH=$PATH:bin`. I double checked to see if the `bin` directory was added to `PATH`, and it was. I can run the script only in the `bin` directory or my user directory. But if I navigate to macbook > documents, for example, and attempt to execute the script by typing `my_script`it will not execute. I receive the following error: `-bash: bin/my_script: No such file or directory`

Why is my script not executing in these other directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the absolute path to $PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

otherwise the shell will always search for a bin subdirectory of the current directory (which only works when your current directory is $HOME)

Comment: Yeah, I think I said that in the last sentence. "You need" -> in his situation, given his desired outcome

Answer (score 3):

`bin/` means the `bin` folder, in the current directory. So, for it to work anywhere, change the path to include `/Users/user/bin`, the absolute path, that is not dependent on the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the complete path to your `bin` directory, not just `bin`.  If `bin` is in your `$HOME`, you can add `$HOME/bin` or `~/bin`.